Three.js GLTF Objects Not Clickable at Correct Positions in Panoramic View
I am trying to load and display GLTF 3D objects in a Three.js panoramic view using krpano. While the objects are displayed, clicking on them does not work as expected. When I click on an object, it seems like the click is registered on an object at a different position, often 180 degrees opposite in the panoramic view.
Example
As shown in the attached image below, if I click on the blue color box, the click event is triggered for an object positioned near the green pyramid, which is located 180 degrees opposite to the blue color box.

I am attaching the krpano three js plugin I am using here.
/*
    krpano ThreeJS example plugin
    - use three.js inside krpano
    - with stereo-rendering and WebVR support
    - with 3d object hit-testing (onover, onout, onup, ondown, onclick) and mouse cursor handling
*/

function krpanoplugin() {
    var local = this;
    var krpano = null;
    var device = null;
    var plugin = null;

    local.registerplugin = function (krpanointerface, pluginpath, pluginobject) {
        krpano = krpanointerface;
        device = krpano.device;
        plugin = pluginobject;

        if (krpano.version < "1.19") {
            krpano.trace(3, "ThreeJS plugin - too old krpano version (min. 1.19)");
            return;
        }

        if (!device.webgl) {
            // show warning
            krpano.trace(2, "ThreeJS plugin - WebGL required");
            return;
        }

        krpano.debugmode = true;
        krpano.trace(0, "ThreeJS krpano plugin");

        // load the requiered three.js scripts
        // load_scripts(["three.min.js"], start);

        // load_scripts(["three.js", "MTLLoader.js", "OBJLoader.js"], start);
        load_scripts(["three.js", "GLTFLoader.js"], start);

    }

    local.unloadplugin = function () {
        // no unloading support at the moment
        plugin = null;
        krpano = null;
    }

    local.onresize = function (width, height) {
        return false;
    }


    function resolve_url_path(url) {
        if (url.charAt(0) != "/" && url.indexOf("://") < 0) {
            // adjust relative url path
            url = krpano.parsepath("%CURRENTXML%/" + url);
        }

        return url;
    }


    function load_scripts(urls, callback) {
        if (urls.length > 0) {
            var url = resolve_url_path(urls.splice(0, 1)[0]);

            var script = document.createElement("script");
            script.src = url;
            script.addEventListener("load", function () { load_scripts(urls, callback); });
            script.addEventListener("error", function () { krpano.trace(3, "loading file '" + url + "' failed!"); });
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
        }
        else {
            // done
            callback();
        }
    }


    // helper
    var M_RAD = Math.PI / 180.0;


    // ThreeJS/krpano objects
    var renderer = null;
    var scene = null;
    var camera = null;
    // var perspectivecamera = null;
    var stereocamera = null;
    var camera_hittest_raycaster = null;
    var krpano_panoview = null;
    var krpano_panoview_euler = null;
    var krpano_projection = new Float32Array(16);       // krpano projection matrix
    var krpano_depthbuffer_scale = 1.0001;              // depthbuffer scaling (use ThreeJS defaults: znear=0.1, zfar=2000)
    var krpano_depthbuffer_offset = -0.2;
    var sceneMeshes = []


    function start() {
        // create the ThreeJS WebGL renderer, but use the WebGL context from krpano
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: krpano.webGL.canvas, context: krpano.webGL.context, antialias: false });
        renderer.autoClear = false;
        renderer.setPixelRatio(1);  // krpano handles the pixel ratio scaling
        // restore the krpano WebGL settings (for correct krpano rendering)
        restore_krpano_WebGL_state();

        // use the krpano onviewchanged event as render-frame callback (this event will be directly called after the krpano pano rendering)
        krpano.set("events[__threejs__].keep", true);
        krpano.set("events[__threejs__].onviewchange", adjust_krpano_rendering);    // correct krpano view settings before the rendering
        krpano.set("events[__threejs__].onviewchanged", render_frame);

        // enable continuous rendering (that means render every frame, not just when the view has changed)
        krpano.view.continuousupdates = true;

        // register mouse and touch events
        if (device.browser.events.mouse) {
            krpano.control.layer.addEventListener("mousedown", handle_mouse_touch_events, true);
        }

        if (device.browser.events.touch) {
            krpano.control.layer.addEventListener(device.browser.events.touchstart, handle_mouse_touch_events, true);
        }

        // basic ThreeJS objects
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.25, 1000);// new THREE.Camera()

        // console.log("cameracamera", camera);
        stereocamera = new THREE.Camera();
        camera_hittest_raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
        krpano_panoview_euler = new THREE.Euler();

        // build the ThreeJS scene (start adding custom code there)
        build_scene();
        // restore the krpano WebGL settings (for correct krpano rendering)
        restore_krpano_WebGL_state();
    }


    function restore_krpano_WebGL_state() {
        var gl = krpano.webGL.context;

        gl.disable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.cullFace(gl.FRONT);
        gl.frontFace(gl.CCW);
        gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
        gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
        gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, false);
        gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_PREMULTIPLY_ALPHA_WEBGL, false);
        gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);

        // restore the current krpano WebGL program
        krpano.webGL.restoreProgram();
        // console.log("rendererrenderer", renderer);
        renderer.resetState()
        //renderer.resetGLState();
    }


    function restore_ThreeJS_WebGL_state() {
        var gl = krpano.webGL.context;

        gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL);
        gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
        gl.cullFace(gl.BACK);
        gl.clearDepth(1);
        gl.clear(gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        renderer.resetState()
        // renderer.resetGLState();
    }


    function krpano_projection_matrix(sw, sh, zoom, xoff, yoff) {
        var m = krpano_projection;

        var pr = device.pixelratio;
        sw = pr / (sw * 0.5);
        sh = pr / (sh * 0.5);

        m[0] = zoom * sw; m[1] = 0; m[2] = 0; m[3] = 0;
        m[4] = 0; m[5] = -zoom * sh; m[6] = 0; m[7] = 0;
        m[8] = xoff; m[9] = -yoff * sh; m[10] = krpano_depthbuffer_scale; m[11] = 1;
        m[12] = 0; m[13] = 0; m[14] = krpano_depthbuffer_offset; m[15] = 1;
    }


    function update_camera_matrix(camera) {
        var m = krpano_projection;
        camera.projectionMatrix.set(m[0], m[4], m[8], m[12], m[1], m[5], m[9], m[13], m[2], m[6], m[10], m[14], m[3], m[7], m[11], m[15]);
    }


    function adjust_krpano_rendering() {
        if (krpano.view.fisheye != 0.0) {
            // disable the fisheye distortion, ThreeJS objects can't be rendered with it
            krpano.view.fisheye = 0.0;
        }
    }


    function render_frame() {
        var gl = krpano.webGL.context;
        var vr = krpano.webVR && krpano.webVR.enabled ? krpano.webVR : null;

        var sw = gl.drawingBufferWidth;
        var sh = gl.drawingBufferHeight;


        // setup WebGL for ThreeJS
        restore_ThreeJS_WebGL_state();

        // set the camera/view rotation
        krpano_panoview = krpano.view.getState(krpano_panoview);    // the 'krpano_panoview' object will be created and cached inside getState()
        krpano_panoview_euler.set(-krpano_panoview.v * M_RAD, (krpano_panoview.h - 90) * M_RAD, krpano_panoview.r * M_RAD, "YXZ");
        camera.quaternion.setFromEuler(krpano_panoview_euler);
        camera.updateMatrixWorld(true);

        // set the camera/view projection
        krpano_projection_matrix(sw, sh, krpano_panoview.z, 0, krpano_panoview.yf);
        update_camera_matrix(camera);


        // do scene updates
        update_scene();


        // render the scene
        if (krpano.display.stereo == false) {
            // normal rendering
            renderer.setViewport(0, 0, sw, sh);
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }
        else {
            // stereo / VR rendering
            sw *= 0.5;  // use half screen width

            var stereo_scale = 0.05;
            var stereo_offset = Number(krpano.display.stereooverlap);

            // use a different camera for stereo rendering to keep the normal one for hit-testing
            stereocamera.quaternion.copy(camera.quaternion);
            stereocamera.updateMatrixWorld(true);

            // render left eye
            var eye_offset = -0.03;
            krpano_projection_matrix(sw, sh, krpano_panoview.z, stereo_offset, krpano_panoview.yf);

            if (vr) {
                eye_offset = vr.eyetranslt(1);                      // get the eye offset (from the WebVR API)
                vr.prjmatrix(1, krpano_projection);                 // replace the projection matrix (with the one from WebVR)
                krpano_projection[10] = krpano_depthbuffer_scale;   // adjust the depthbuffer scaling
                krpano_projection[14] = krpano_depthbuffer_offset;
            }

            // add the eye offset
            krpano_projection[12] = krpano_projection[0] * -eye_offset * stereo_scale;

            update_camera_matrix(stereocamera);
            renderer.setViewport(0, 0, sw, sh);
            renderer.render(scene, stereocamera);

            // render right eye
            eye_offset = +0.03;
            krpano_projection[8] = -stereo_offset;  // mod the projection matrix (only change the stereo offset)

            if (vr) {
                eye_offset = vr.eyetranslt(2);                      // get the eye offset (from the WebVR API)
                vr.prjmatrix(2, krpano_projection);                 // replace the projection matrix (with the one from WebVR)
                krpano_projection[10] = krpano_depthbuffer_scale;   // adjust the depthbuffer scaling
                krpano_projection[14] = krpano_depthbuffer_offset;
            }

            // add the eye offset
            krpano_projection[12] = krpano_projection[0] * -eye_offset * stereo_scale;

            update_camera_matrix(stereocamera);
            renderer.setViewport(sw, 0, sw, sh);
            renderer.render(scene, stereocamera);
        }

        // important - restore the krpano WebGL state for correct krpano rendering
        restore_krpano_WebGL_state();
    }



    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // ThreeJS User Content - START HERE

    var clock = null;
    var animatedobjects = [];
    var box = null;


    // add a krpano hotspot like handling for the 3d objects
    function assign_object_properties(obj, name, properties) {
        // set defaults (krpano hotspot like properties)
        // console.log(obj.scale);
        // if (properties === undefined) properties = {};
        if (properties.name === undefined) properties.name = name;
        if (properties.ath === undefined) properties.ath = 0;
        if (properties.atv === undefined) properties.atv = 0;
        if (properties.depth === undefined) properties.depth = 1000;
        if (properties.scale === undefined) properties.scale = 1;
        if (properties.rx === undefined) properties.rx = 0;
        if (properties.ry === undefined) properties.ry = 0;
        if (properties.rz === undefined) properties.rz = 0;
        if (properties.rorder === undefined) properties.rorder = "YXZ";
        if (properties.enabled === undefined) properties.enabled = true;
        if (properties.capture === undefined) properties.capture = true;
        if (properties.onover === undefined) properties.onover = null;
        if (properties.onout === undefined) properties.onout = null;
        if (properties.ondown === undefined) properties.ondown = null;
        if (properties.onup === undefined) properties.onup = null;
        if (properties.onclick === undefined) properties.onclick = null;
        properties.pressed = false;
        properties.hovering = false;
        properties.scale = obj.scale
        obj.properties = properties;
        update_object_properties(obj);
    }


    function update_object_properties(obj) {
        var p = obj.properties;
        var px = p.depth * Math.cos(p.atv * M_RAD) * Math.cos((180 - p.ath) * M_RAD);
        var py = p.depth * Math.sin(p.atv * M_RAD);
        var pz = p.depth * Math.cos(p.atv * M_RAD) * Math.sin((180 - p.ath) * M_RAD);
        obj.position.set(px, py, pz);
        obj.rotation.set(p.rx * M_RAD, p.ry * M_RAD, p.rz * M_RAD, p.rorder);

        obj.updateMatrixWorld()
    }


    function load_object_gltf(url, properties, donecall = null) {
        url = resolve_url_path(url);
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
            loader.load(url, function (gltf) {

                const box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(gltf.scene);
                const center = box.getCenter(new THREE.Vector3());

                gltf.scene.traverse(function (child) {

                    if (child.isMesh) {
                        // console.log(child);
                        const { geometry, material } = child;
                        geometry.computeVertexNormals();
                        geometry.center()
                        var obj = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

                        child.position.set(100, 100, 100);
                        child.material.transparent = true;
                        child.material.metalness = 0;
                        child.visible = true;
                        child.castShadow = true;
                        child.receiveShadow = true;
                        material.side = THREE.BackSide;
                        sceneMeshes.push(child)

                        assign_object_properties(child, url, properties);

                    }
                });

                scene.add(gltf.scene);
                gltf.scene.scale.set(-1, -1, -1)
                resolve(gltf.scene);
            })
        })
    }
    console.log();
    function build_scene() {
        clock = new THREE.Clock();

        load_object_gltf("Test.glb", {
            ath: 0, atv: 0, depth: 1, scale: 1, rx: 0, ry: 0, rz: 180,
            ondown: function (obj) { obj.properties.scale *= 2; update_object_properties(obj); },
            // onup: function (obj) { console.log("objobj", obj); obj.properties.scale /= 1.2; update_object_properties(obj); }
        }).then((obj) => {
            console.log(obj);
            obj.children.forEach((elem) => {
                // elem.children[0].material.opacity = 0.5
            })
        })

        scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xFFFFFF));

        var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xFFFFFF);
        directionalLight.position.x = 0.5;
        directionalLight.position.y = -1;
        directionalLight.position.z = 0;
        directionalLight.position.normalize();
        scene.add(directionalLight);
    }

    //handling click event 
    // document.addEventListener('click', onClick);
    function onClick(event) {
        console.log("Clicked");
        // let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
        let object = getFirstObjectWithName(event, window, camera, scene);

    }

    function getFirstObjectWithName(event, window, camera, scene) {
        // const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
        const getFirstValue = true;
        const mousePointer = getMouseVector3(event, window);
        const intersections = checkRayIntersections(mousePointer, camera, camera_hittest_raycaster, scene, getFirstValue);
        console.log(mousePointer.y)
    }

    function getMouseVector3(event, window) {
        let mousePointer = new THREE.Vector3();

        // mousePointer.x = (krpano.mouse.x / krpano.area.pixelwidth) * 2.0 - 1.0;
        // mousePointer.y = (krpano.mouse.x / krpano.area.pixelheight) * 2.0 - 1.0;
        mousePointer.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
        mousePointer.y = (-(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1) * -1;

        return mousePointer;
    }

    function checkRayIntersections(mousePointer, camera, raycaster, scene) {
        camera_hittest_raycaster.setFromCamera(mousePointer, camera);
        // scene.add(new THREE.ArrowHelper(camera_hittest_raycaster.ray.direction, raycaster.ray.origin, 300, 0xff0000));

        let intersections = camera_hittest_raycaster.intersectObjects(sceneMeshes, true);
        let intersectObj = ""
        intersections.forEach((obj) => {
            intersectObj += obj.object.name + " ";
            obj.object.material.opacity = 0.2
        })
        console.log("intersections", intersections, intersectObj);

        // console.log(scene);

        // intersections[0].object.scale.x *= 2
        // intersections[0].object.scale.y *= 2
        // intersections[0].object.scale.z *= 2

    }
    function do_object_hittest(mx, my) {
        var mouse_x = (mx / krpano.area.pixelwidth) * 2.0 - 1.0;
        var mouse_y = (my / krpano.area.pixelheight) * 2.0 - 1.0;

        if (krpano.display.stereo) {
            mouse_x += (mouse_x < 0.0 ? +1 : -1) * (1.0 - Number(krpano.display.stereooverlap)) * 0.5;
        }

        camera_hittest_raycaster.ray.direction.set(mouse_x, -mouse_y, 1.0).unproject(camera).normalize();

        // scene.add(new THREE.ArrowHelper(camera_hittest_raycaster.ray.direction, camera_hittest_raycaster.ray.origin, 300, 0xff0000));
        // console.log("camera_hittest_raycaster", camera_hittest_raycaster);
        // console.log("scenescene", scene);
        // if (scene.children.length < 3) {
        //  return
        // }
        var intersects = camera_hittest_raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);
        // console.log("intersects", intersects);
        var i;
        var obj;
        for (i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++) {
            obj = intersects[i].object;
            if (obj && obj.properties && obj.properties.enabled) {
                return obj;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }


    var handle_mouse_hitobject = null;

    function handle_mouse_touch_events(event) {
        var type = "";

        if (event.type == "mousedown") {
            type = "ondown";
            // handle_mouse_click(event)
            krpano.control.layer.addEventListener("mouseup", handle_mouse_touch_events, true);
        }
        else if (event.type == "mouseup") {
            type = "onup";
            krpano.control.layer.removeEventListener("mouseup", handle_mouse_touch_events, true);
        }
        else if (event.type == device.browser.events.touchstart) {
            type = "ondown";
            krpano.control.layer.addEventListener(device.browser.events.touchend, handle_mouse_touch_events, true);
        }
        else if (event.type == device.browser.events.touchend) {
            type = "onup";
            krpano.control.layer.removeEventListener(device.browser.events.touchend, handle_mouse_touch_events, true);
        }

        // get mouse / touch pos
        var ms = krpano.control.getMousePos(event.changedTouches ? event.changedTouches[0] : event);
        ms.x /= krpano.stagescale;
        ms.y /= krpano.stagescale;

        // is there a object as that pos?
        var hitobj = do_object_hittest(ms.x, ms.y);

        if (type == "ondown") {
            if (hitobj) {
                handle_mouse_hitobject = hitobj;

                hitobj.properties.pressed = true;

                if (hitobj.properties.ondown) {
                    hitobj.properties.ondown(hitobj);
                }

                if (hitobj.properties.capture) {
                    krpano.mouse.down = true;
                    //event.stopPropagation();

                    console.log(hitobj)
                }

                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
        else if (type == "onup") {
            if (handle_mouse_hitobject && handle_mouse_hitobject.properties.enabled) {
                if (handle_mouse_hitobject.properties.pressed) {
                    handle_mouse_hitobject.properties.pressed = false;

                    if (handle_mouse_hitobject.properties.onup) {
                        handle_mouse_hitobject.properties.onup(handle_mouse_hitobject);
                    }
                }

                if (handle_mouse_hitobject.properties.onclick) {
                    if (hitobj == handle_mouse_hitobject) {
                        handle_mouse_hitobject.properties.onclick(handle_mouse_hitobject);
                    }
                }
            }

            krpano.mouse.down = false;
        }
    }

    function handle_mouse_click(event) {
        // Get mouse position
        var ms = krpano.control.getMousePos(event);
        var mouse_x = (ms.x / krpano.stagescale) * 2.0 - 1.0;
        var mouse_y = (ms.y / krpano.stagescale) * 2.0 - 1.0;

        // Perform hit testing to check if an object was clicked
        var hitobj = do_object_hittest(mouse_x, mouse_y);

        // Handle the clicked object
        if (hitobj) {
            // Perform actions based on the clicked object
            console.log("Clicked object:", hitobj);

            // Example: Change object properties or trigger custom event callbacks
            if (hitobj.properties.onclick) {
                hitobj.properties.onclick(hitobj);
            }
        }
    }


    function handle_mouse_hovering() {
        // check mouse over state
        if (krpano.mouse.down == false)     // currently not dragging?
        {
            var hitobj = do_object_hittest(krpano.mouse.x, krpano.mouse.y);
            // console.log("hitobjhitobj", hitobj);
            if (hitobj != handle_mouse_hitobject) {
                if (handle_mouse_hitobject) {
                    handle_mouse_hitobject.properties.hovering = false;
                    if (handle_mouse_hitobject.properties.onout) handle_mouse_hitobject.properties.onout(handle_mouse_hitobject);
                }

                if (hitobj) {
                    hitobj.properties.hovering = true;
                    if (hitobj.properties.onover) hitobj.properties.onover(hitobj);
                }

                handle_mouse_hitobject = hitobj;
            }

            if (handle_mouse_hitobject)// || (krpano.display.stereo == false && krpano.display.hotspotrenderer != "webgl"))
            {
                krpano.control.layer.style.cursor = krpano.cursors.hit;
            }
            else {
                krpano.cursors.update();
            }
        }
    }


    function update_scene() {
        // animate objects
        var delta = clock.getDelta();

        if (box) {
            box.properties.rx += 50 * delta;
            box.properties.ry += 10 * delta;
            update_object_properties(box);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < animatedobjects.length; i++) {
            animatedobjects[i].updateAnimation(1000 * delta);
        }

        handle_mouse_hovering();
    }


}```


How can I ensure that the objects are clickable at their correct positions in the panoramic view? Any suggestions on what might be causing the discrepancy in click detection?


I have set up raycasting to detect clicks and assigned properties to the objects to handle interactions. However, the objects are not clickable at their correct positions.

I have tried rotate the scene and position. 
Objects are visible in the correct positions but clicks are registered on objects in different positions.

